# Web Application for display raster data on basis of time slider

Tags: postgis, javascript, leaflet

It May act as a duplicate question to many, but i have tried refering too all the questions related to my questions, but i am still confiused.

Below in attached my code. which i use for Web Mapping

```
        <div id="map">

   </div>


        <div id="nav">hello</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">



  var wmslayers = L.layerGroup();


   var latit = <?php echo $latitude ?>; // Get latitude from php variable to js variable
   var langt = <?php echo $longitude ?>; // Get longitude from php variable to js variable
   var zom = <?php echo $zooms ?>; // get zoom value from php variable to js variable
   var wmsl = <?php echo $wmslay ?>; //way to get wmy layer from php variable



    //Leaflet provider plugin to access different layers.
    var osmLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        thunLink = '<a href="http://thunderforest.com/">Thunderforest</a>',
        esrilink = '<a href="http://esri.com/">ESRI MAPS</a>';


    var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        osmAttrib = '&copy; ' + osmLink + ' Contributors',
        landUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        thunAttrib = '&copy; '+osmLink+' Contributors & '+thunLink,
        esriurl= 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        esriAttrib= '&copy;'+esrilink+'Contributors';

    var osmMap = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib}),
        landMap = L.tileLayer(landUrl, {attribution: thunAttrib}),
        esriMap = L.tileLayer(esriurl, {attribution: esriAttrib});

    var map = L.map('map', {layers: [esriMap] // only add one!
    })
    .setView([latit, langt], zom);

      var baseLayers = {
                        "OSM Mapnik": osmMap,
                         "Landscape": landMap,
                         "Street":esriMap
                       };
                          map.on('click', function(e) {
                                        alert(e.latlng);
                                                        });

          L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);


     //ways to add wms service from geoserver to leaflet map
     wmslayers.addTo(map); 

     var wms_service = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/raster/wms", 
     {
      layers: wmsl,
      format: 'image/png',
      transparent: true,
      version: '1.1.1',
      attribution: "",
      tiled:true
        });

     wmslayers.addLayer(wms_service);
      wms_service.bringToFront(); 


  // script to load geojson or kml file and also custoom icon has been assigned.
    var style = {color:'red', opacity: 1.0, fillOpacity: 1.0, weight: 2, 
                    clickable: false};
    L.Control.FileLayerLoad.LABEL = '<i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>';
    L.Control.fileLayerLoad({
        fitBounds: true,
        layerOptions: {style: style,
                       pointToLayer: function (data, latlng) {
                        var myIcon = L.icon({iconSize: [15, 15], iconUrl: 'img/Map-Marker-Bubble-Azure-icon.png'});
                          return L.marker(latlng, {icon: myIcon });
                       }},
    }).addTo(map);
      /// this adds the reverse geolocation  attribute
    var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.OSMGeocoder();
    map.addControl(osmGeocoder);



      //Create the opacity controls -- 


    var higherOpacity = new L.Control.higherOpacity();
                        map.addControl(higherOpacity);
    var lowerOpacity = new L.Control.lowerOpacity();
                        map.addControl(lowerOpacity);
    var opacitySlider = new L.Control.opacitySlider();
                        map.addControl(opacitySlider);

//Specify the layer for which you want to modify the opacity. Note that the setOpacityLayer() method applies to all the controls.
//You only need to call it once. 

    opacitySlider.setOpacityLayer(wms_service);

//Set initial opacity to 0.5 (Optional)
    wms_service.setOpacity(0.5);


    </script>
    </body>
```

With this code i am able to display data onto leaflet map with a click of a button and also able to control the opacity of that. Now I want to display different raster images coming from geoserver according to time slider, basically trying to depict Urbanization growth in city.

Any leads on how should i go about it, will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

It seemed to me you need some kind of layer switcher. You want to switch between layers using a controller. You can implement function below on your code. Then you need to call this function everytime time slider changes.

```
    function switchLayer() {
        var layers = [];
        //Push all active layers to an array
        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if (layer instanceof L.TileLayer)
                layers.push(layer);
        });
        layers.forEach(element => {
            if (element._url == layer1._url) {
                map.removeLayer(layer1);
                map.addLayer(layer2);
            } else if (element._url == layer2._url) {
                map.removeLayer(layer2);
                map.addLayer(layer1);
            }
        });
    }
```